# ASP.NET Dependency Injection: Some services are not able to be constructed

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, dependency-injection

I created an .NET MVC application and made use of Dependency Injection and Repository Pattern However, I realised i am getting the following error when i added the POST method to my project for posting data to database.

```
System.AggregateException: 'Some services are not able to be constructed (Error while validating 
the service descriptor 'ServiceType: FluentHibernateTest.IBookService Lifetime: Scoped 
ImplementationType: FluentHibernateTest.Models.BookService': Unable to resolve service for type 
'FluentHibernateTest.Models.IRepository' while attempting to activate 
'FluentHibernateTest.Models.BookService'.)'
```

**NhibernateHelper.cs**

```
public static class NhibernateHelper
{
    public static ISessionFactory _sessionFactory { get; private set; }
    public static Configuration configuration { get; set; }

    //static string _connectionstring;
    public static void InitializeConnection(string connectionString)
    {
        _sessionFactory = Fluently.Configure()
            .Database(MsSqlConfiguration.MsSql2008
                .Driver<MicrosoftDataSqlClientDriver>()
                .ConnectionString(connectionString).ShowSql)
            .Mappings(m => m
            .FluentMappings.AddFromAssemblyOf<Book>())
            .BuildSessionFactory();
    }
}
```

**BookController.cs**

```
public IActionResult Post([FromBody] Book Book)
{
    try
    {
        Book newBook = _IbookService.AddBook(Book);
        return new ObjectResult(newBook);
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        throw ex;
    }
}
```

**Repository.cs**

```
ISession _session;

public Repository(ISession session)
{
    _session = session;
}

 public Book AddBook(Book Book)
{
    return _session.Save(Book) as Book;
}
```

**BookService.cs**

```
private readonly IRepository _repository;

public BookService(IRepository repository)
{
    this._repository = repository;
}

public Book AddBook(Book Book)
{
    Book entity = null;
    entity = _repository.AddBook(Book);
    return entity;
}
```

**Startup.cs**

```
services.AddControllersWithViews();
services.AddSingleton<IBookService,BookService>();
services.AddSingleton<IBookController, BookController>();
services.AddSingleton<IRepository, Repository>();

services.AddHttpClient();

services.AddSession();
services.AddDistributedMemoryCache();
services.AddMvc();
```

Can someone explain what im doing wrong?

Comment: The most likely cause of this issue is that you defined a second `IRepository` interface (or class) meaning that the call to `services.AddSingleton<IRepository, Repository>()` refers to a different type named `IRepository` than the `IRepository` referenced by `BookService`.

Comment: @Steven I have a containerConfig.cs class where i have ```builder.RegisterType<Repository>().As<IRepository>();
            builder.RegisterType<BookService>().As<IBookService>();
            builder.RegisterType<Application>().As<IApplication>();
            builder.RegisterType<BookController>().As<IBookController>();```

Comment: What's the namespace of the `IRepository` that is referenced by the code `services.AddSingleton<IRepository, Repository>()`? You can check this by putting the cursor on that line on the `IRepository` word and than pressing `F12` (goto reference). That will jump you to that type. What's its namespace?

Comment: @Steven It is ```FluentHibernateTest.Models.IRepository``` . Although IRepository is not on the Models folder.

Comment: Do you have two `IRepository` types located in different projects?

Comment: I'm going to remove the `autofac` label in here. You don't have Autofac integration shown in the code and no services are registered using Autofac syntax. This is all Microsoft built-in DI.